# Haskell - Print numbers

Tags: haskell, printing

I've written following code:

```
module Test where

import Char
import IO

main = do
    str <- readFile "no.txt"
    putStrLn (show(english str))

string2list :: String -> [String]
string2list "" = []
string2list s = words s


english :: String -> Int
english s
    | head (string2list s) == "one"     = 1
    | head (string2list s) == "two"     = 2
    | head (string2list s) == "three"   = 3
    | head (string2list s) == "four"    = 4
    | head (string2list s) == "five"    = 5
    | head (string2list s) == "six"     = 6
    | head (string2list s) == "seven"   = 7
    | head (string2list s) == "eight"   = 8
    | head (string2list s) == "nine"    = 9
    | otherwise                         = error "not match"
```

And in no.txt:

```
one
two
three
four
....
```

After compiled and run the code, I got the result:

```
1
```

But I expect to get:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

What's wrong with the code? Any help? thx!

Comment: Just a hint: If you wish your program to process each line in the input, it would make sense that somewhere you would be converting the input (which is currently just one long String value) into seperate `lines`.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but `words ""` is `[]`, so you can get rid of `string2list` and just use `words` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str` is not list of String (it's just a String like `one\ntwo`) when read from `readFile`. Do

```
main = do
    str <- readFile "no.txt"
    mapM_ (\x -> putStrLn (show(english x))) $ lines str
```

in your `main` instead and convert `str` to a list using `lines` (see doc of [lines](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3alines) ).

Comment: Your code works but I think your remark on why his fails is wrong since it is the case that `lines . words == words` and he uses words. I think focus should be given to the fact that you are mapping `english` onto the list of lines. On a stylistic note `putStrLn . show == print`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer to your question but rather a stylistic advice. You can get rid of those wordy `head (string2list s)` things by using pattern matching and by replacing `string2list` with `words`; both do exactly the same thing:

```
english s = case words s of
  "one"   :_ -> 1
  "two"   :_ -> 2
  "three" :_ -> 3
  "four"  :_ -> 4
  "five"  :_ -> 5
  "six"   :_ -> 6 
  "seven" :_ -> 7
  "eight" :_ -> 8 
  "nine"  :_ -> 9
  _          -> error "no match"
```

Comment: This also give a significant performance boost (since words is evaluated repeatedly, once for each guard, in the original solution).

Comment: @Jonas additionally, GHC is smart enough to merge similar cases if you use an ordinary pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `english` only looks at the first word. Your file comes in as

```
"one\ntwo\nthree\nfour"
```

Then `words` turns that into:

```
["one","two","three","four"]
```

Using head on that gives you:

```
"one"
```

And therefor `1` is printed.

Instaid we would like to use english on all the words. That is when `map` comes in
handy, but in this case we are mapping an IO action onto the list, so we want to use `mapM`. Furthermore we are not interested in the outcome of the IO action (we just want the action to happen) so we use `mapM_`:

```
import Control.Monad

main = do
  str <- readFile "no.txt"
  mapM_ (print . english) (words str)

english "one"   = 1
english "two"   = 2
english "three" = 3
english "four"  = 4
english "five"  = 5
english "six"   = 6 
english "seven" = 7
english "eight" = 8 
english "nine"  = 9
```

Note that it is possible to write this using `map` instaid of `mapM` by first making `["one","two","three",...]` into `["1","2","3"]`, concating those strings, and then using `putStrLn`, but the above way is both shorter and more idiomatic.